# How to redirect to a different php document in htaccess file

Tags: htaccess

Currently I have the following htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex .base.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule . .base.php
```

how can I modify this in order to redirect to another php file (image.php) based
on if the URL contains a .png extension but still have any other page go to .base.php?